# How can I return unique_ptr from factory method?

Tags: c++, factory

I have a few classes with heroes that are extended from abstract class Warrior:

```
enum Warrior_ID { Infantryman_ID=0, Archer_ID, Horseman_ID };

class Warrior
{
  public:
    virtual void info() = 0;
    virtual ~Warrior() { }
    static unique_ptr<Warrior> createWarrior( Warrior_ID id );
};

class Infantryman: public Warrior
{
  public:
    void info()
    {
      cout << "Infantryman" << endl;
    }
};

class Archer: public Warrior
{
  public:
    void info()
    {
      cout << "Archer" << endl;
    }
};

class Horseman: public Warrior
{
  public:
    void info()
    {
      cout << "Horseman" << endl;
    }
};
```

And this is my factory method, that returns specific character:

```
unique_ptr<Warrior> Warrior::createWarrior( Warrior_ID id )
{
    unique_ptr<Warrior> p;
    switch (id)
    {
        case Infantryman_ID:
            p = new Infantryman(); //this doesn't work
            break;
        case Archer_ID:
            p = new Archer(); //this doesn't work
            break;
        case Horseman_ID:
            p = new Horseman(); //this doesn't work
            break;
        default:
    }
   return p;
};
```

How can I return unique_ptr with specific character without using make_unique ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr`'s [pointer constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) is explicit, so you need

```
p = std::unique_ptr<Warrior>{new Infantryman{}};
```

Alternatively, use the `reset()` member function:

```
p.reset(new Infantryman{});
```

As noted in comments, you don't really need to declare a local variable `p` and then modify it. You can return directly from the switch block:

```
    case Infantryman_ID:
        return std::unique_ptr<Warrior>{new Infantryman{}};
    case Archer_ID:
        return std::unique_ptr<Warrior>{new Archer{}};
```

and so on.

Comment: Or get rid of the local variable altogether - `return  unique_ptr<Warrior>( new Infantryman());`

Comment: @NeilButterworth Indeed. Got me thinking about RVO and all that until I remembered it doesn't really matter in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If your coding standards allow using templates, you could write your factory method as:

```
template<typename T>
static unique_ptr<Warrior> createWarrior()
{
    return unique_ptr<Warrior> { new T{} };
}
```

And at the calling site, use:

```
unique_ptr<Warrior> archer1 = WarriorFactory::create<Archer>();
unique_ptr<Warrior> horseman1 = WarriorFactory::create<Horseman>();
```

etc